# Using Cover my ass and Tor

Tags: vpn

When it comes to VPN's I'm a newbie. I recently purchased cover my ass. If I start CMA and get my VPN IP Address then start Tor does Tor use my VPN Address? Will I have a double protection from Big Brothers eyes? Or will Tor simply use my Normal IP Address?

Comment: What is the threat you are trying to mitigate?

Answer (score 1):

I think this would not add any useful security beyond what Tor gives you already.  And also there's the chance of this even adding another way to identify you that does not exist with Tor alone.

Tor exit nodes can't identify you; but they can read your plain text transmissions. A VPN, on the other hand requires some sort of authentication and knows at least your IP address. And who knows what else? How much do you trust it?  Basically this means there is a machine somewhere that is entirely out of your control that might be able to link your machine (or at lease ip/mac address) to web traffic sent through Tor.